# Use custom type face in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences

How to change type face of `PreferenceScreen` to use a custom font? Because `PreferenceScreen` is a final class, there is no way to extend it and set its type face in `onBindView(View)`.

Comment: You can change the font of the whole system, but I guess this is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to iterate over all widgets in your `PreferenceActivity`, find those inheriting from `TextView`, and adjust their font. Bear in mind, though, that this will only affect the `PreferenceActivity`, not any dialogs those `Preference` objects display.